# knitr "&" in printed string is breaking LaTeX

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am using knitr to format a report that includes a batch of strings that sometimes include a LaTeX special character -- in this case an ampersand (&).  Knitr inserts the text correctly in the LaTeX code, but the LaTeX compile fails with a "misplaced &" message.  I guess that I could do a search and replace on the *.tex file, escaping all the special characters.  But I am wondering whether there is a way to insert these strings so that the escaping is done automatically.  Thanks for any help that any of you can give me on this.

Answer (score 2):

No reproducible example, no answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
print('&')
@
\end{document}
```

Worked well.

Comment: guessing: maybe OP is using something like `\Sexpr{"a&b"}` ? (I haven't tried this)

Comment: @BenBolker Maybe. In that case, yes, it will fail, since knitr does not escape the output of inline expressions. Before the OP confirms it, I'm not going to spend time on guessing.